# How to repeat a method every x-coordinate

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm fresh to iOS Programming, I'm trying my first test as a very simple game , so in this game I want to repeat a function every time the object reach y=80.

The problem in my code that the objects disappear and regenerate from the beginning ,so how can I repeat it?

```
-(void) TreeMoving{

Tree1.center=CGPointMake(Tree1.center.x, Tree1.center.y+1);
Tree2.center=CGPointMake(Tree2.center.x, Tree2.center.y+1);
Tree3.center=CGPointMake(Tree3.center.x, Tree3.center.y+1);


if (Tree1.center.y>590) {
    [self PlaceTrees];
}
```

Comment: Please, name your methods and var starting with a lowercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the modulo ( % ) operator.
Try this :

```
    if (Tree1.center.y % 80 == 0)
      {
       [self PlaceTrees];
      }
```